# Passport.js Session Confusion

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am learning node and express. I am trying to build a very basic app that will simply let a user log in using json. Then will maintain session until they log out. With asp.net this is a doddle you just set it up in the config and call...

```
Auth.Login(username,pasword)
```

When they log out you just do:

```
Auth.logout()
```

And if you need to check if they are logged in you simply do:

```
Auth.IsLoggedIn()
```

Or code to that effect. Well seems like Passport for node is just not that simple. I spent all night getting this working...

```
app.post('/authentication/login', function handleLocalAuthentication(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

        // Manually establish the session...
        req.login({username:'me@me.com',password:'password'}, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.json({
                message: 'user authenticated'
            });
        });

    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/authentication/isauthenticated',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());

})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {

        return done(null, {username:'ss',password:'sffds'});
    }
));
```

So now I have no cookies, no session persisted when I login and then hit the `/authentication/isAuthenticated` url. I can't even get a breakpoint to stop in the strategy...

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {

        console.log('ggg');
        return done(null, {username:'ss',password:'sffds'});

    }
));
```

Am I looking at the wrong solution for this? Should I be rolling my own auth or something with a basic middleware function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local). It's really great and it helped me a lot.

And here's my repo which has implemented passport authentication with users stored in mongodb through mongoose, and hashed passwords. Clone it or just check it out, it should help.
https://github.com/thyforhtian/auth_base.

Comment: @thyforhtian the link to "this tutorial" seem to be broken

Comment: In passportjs it makes sense to use sessions or not depending on what strategy you use. For instance when building a stateless API one would prefer BasicStrategy over LocalStrategy. And @perlamq, there's the link to "this tutorial" mentioned above, I believe: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: Tutorial doesn't exist anymore. link is not working. @thyforhtian please update the answer

Comment: You have the link in @wojjas comment but I've also updated the one in the answer. Not sure about it's content, though.